# Default Comparator for LevelDB

Tags: java, c++, bit-manipulation, leveldb

I'm using LevelDB [from Java via JNI](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni).

I want to supply a numeric (integer) key, and be able to iterate the db in the order of that key. Where I'm having difficulty is understanding how LevelDb's default comparator actually works, and how I would encode an int into a `byte[]` that would let the default comparator correctly order by that `int`.

The LevelDb doco states:

> The preceding examples used the default ordering function for key,
>   which orders bytes lexicographically.

I've googled around but am stumped for how I would actually encode an `int` into *lexicographically ordered bytes*?

Note: If I supply my own comparator, it roughly doubles iteration time as now all the comparisons have to jump back and forth over the JNI boundary, so I don't want to do that.

Comment: Looks like leveldb works on Strings and they are ordered. One thing you can try is to convert your integer to a string and the string prefixed with total digits of the integer. For example, 0-9 is encoded as 10-19. 10-99 is encoded as 210-299. 100-999 is encoded as 3100-3999 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This encoding works:

```
public synchronized static byte[] encode(int key) {
        encoded[0] = (byte)(key >> 24);
        encoded[1] = (byte)(key >> 16);
        encoded[2] = (byte)(key >> 8);
        encoded[3] = (byte)(key);
        return encoded;
    }
```